# Gurgle. Переключение режима препроцессинга

Tags: unix

В [официальной документации](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/timc/gurgle/gurgle.html#SEC4) по языку говорится, что файлы со скриптами могут обрабатываться в разных режимах, но как их переключить не написано.

Кто нибудь знает как это сделать?